# Tags [twitter-fabric] and [fabric-twitter]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

I saw an edit suggestion today which attempted to add both the [twitter-fabric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-fabric) and [fabric-twitter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fabric-twitter) tags to a post.

[twitter-fabric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-fabric) has 118 questions, and a generic wiki entry:

> Twitter Fabric is a mobile SDK and platform which allows developers to build better apps.

[fabric-twitter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fabric-twitter) has 320 questions, with a more defining (granted, not by much) wiki entry:

> Questions about installing and using Fabric, Twitter's mobile SDK suite for iOS and Android

(There is also a [fabric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fabric) tag, which appears to be for an [unrelated Python library](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.10/index.html))

Should we synonymize [twitter-fabric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-fabric) with [fabric-twitter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fabric-twitter), or simply retag all [twitter-fabric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-fabric) posts?

Additionally, what we can do to combat those who may mistag their twitter-related questions with [fabric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fabric) (1,108 questions)?

Comment: I would suggest going the other way; i.e., making [tag:twitter-fabric] the canonical tag, to match the other twitter-* tags.

Comment: Related: [Clean fabric 98% Python, 2% Android](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318610/clean-fabric-98-python-2-android?cb=1)

Comment: [tag:fabric-twitter] is now a synonym of [tag:twitter-fabric] so marking this as completed.

Comment: Can someone add the [meta-tag:synonym-request] tag? I can't edit the post.

Comment: Done @smileycreations15

Answer (score 6):

To solve the problem of having the two tags [twitter-fabric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-fabric) and [fabric-twitter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fabric-twitter), it would make sense to synonymize them, since they both have the same meaning.

For the python [fabric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fabric) I'd suggest making it into a [fabric-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fabric-python) and change existing [fabric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fabric) tags to it, and then make it so that users have to choose between the twitter and python one, and can clearly tell that they're doing so (by making users unable to choose a tag that is just [fabric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fabric).

Comment: It makes most sense (to me) for sorting and lookup to use `fabric-twitter` and `fabric-python` because they share a common prefix.