# Clean [fabric] (98% Python, 2% Android)

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, tag-disambiguation

In two of my latest reviewed edits, the [fabric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fabric) tag was removed from the post, as the context was Android. The current Stack Overflow [fabric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fabric) tag refers to a Python library, but there is also a [build tool framework](https://get.fabric.io/?signup_campaign_id=https://get.fabric.io) for Android called Fabric.

Therefore, I would like to help by searching questions with these tags: [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android)[fabric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fabric). There are about 20 questions. I could easily remove the [fabric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fabric) tag from all them. But, I have read about tags - nuking, splitting, burninating :-), merging, cleaning tags and so on. This subject is not so easy. So before making a mess, I'd like to ask for a short hint:

- Is it ok to remove a not matching tag from a series of questions?
- I assume 20 questions are far too less to suggest splitting [fabric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fabric) into `[fabric.python]` and `[fabric.android]`, right? Or would splitting support the [intention of cleaning the [android] tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252860/help-us-clean-up-the-android-tag)?

I've read this question: [I would like to clean up [like]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286471/i-would-like-to-clean-up-like) which shows me that I'm basically on the right way.

Thank you for any hint.

Comment: Trendy! I'm still stuck in 98% polyester, 2% spandex.

Comment: Somewhat related proposal (related tags): [The \[FAB\] tag is floating everywhere?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/313814/359284)

Comment: I've now cleaned the posts tagged with the mentioned two tags [android] and [fabric]. So this is "cleaning a tag".

Answer (score 46, accepted):

> Is it ok to remove a not matching tag from a series of questions?

Yes, that's definitely ok.

> I assume 20 questions are far too less to suggest splitting [fabric] to [fabric.python] and [fabric.android], right?

It's probably too few to support creating a `[fabric.python]` tag. Since there are over 1100 questions currently tagged [fabric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fabric), and 98% of them are about Python, it's probably better to just leave that tag alone and create one new [fabric-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fabric-android) tag.

Comment: I would also suggest adding an edit to the [tag:fabric] tag-wiki saying something along the lines of "For the android build framework, use [tag:android-fabric]".

Comment: Thank you for encouraging and pointing out the relations. I'll proceed.

Comment: @Matthew: For searchability reasons, I would recommend fabric-android as mentioned by Bill, because it means that people starting to type "fabr" will get the suggestion.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Yeah, I didn't notice until you commented here that I reversed the name from how he did it.  However, the point I was making was that the existing tag should have an instruction stating that it isn't the right tag to use in that case.  I don't mean to suggest an appropriate tag for this, as I don't really have a clue what this framework is, and would leave it to those who know it better to decide on a tag name.

Answer (score 18):

There are already at least three tags related to the framework you're talking about. Take a look at [fabric-twitter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fabric-twitter) (382 Q), [twitter-fabric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-fabric) (123 Q) and [fabric.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fabric.io) (25 Q). Also we have a suspicious [development-fabric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/development-fabric) (3 Q) which probably should be burninated as it is too ambiguous.

So we do not need neither to split [fabric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fabric) (1127 Q) nor to introduce new tags. 
What we actually need is deeper look at what we already have around.

**Edit:**
[twitter-fabric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-fabric) and [fabric-twitter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fabric-twitter) are synonyms now.
[development-fabric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/development-fabric) is gone.

Comment: By the way, Three tags above are not synonyms. Should we care?

Comment: Aha, thank you, I suspected sth like this. That's the kind of judgement I wanted to learn about.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the two Twitter Fabric tags. One of those should be a synonym of the other.

Comment: IMHO [fabric-twitter] and [fabric.io] too should be a synonym for [twitter-fabric].

Comment: Another complaint about the Twitter tags: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314262/tags-twitter-fabric-and-fabric-twitter

Comment: Now Fabric was acquired by Google, which means [twitter-fabric] is no longer relevant. Someone created [google-fabric]..

Comment: See my [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/354469/1000551) with new proposal regarding Fabric's acquisition by Google

Answer (score 3):

So, Fabric was [acquired by Google](https://fabric.io/blog/fabric-joins-google).

I suggest to use [google-fabric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-fabric) and make [twitter-fabric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-fabric) and [fabric.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fabric.io) synonyms for it.
We should leave [fabric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fabric) alone, it belongs to Python tool, as suggested by @bill-the-lizard.

[Fabric+android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fabric+android), [fabric+ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fabric+ios) questions should be retagged.

If you have other suggestions for my proposal, please leave them in comments.